# App did Build but it doesn't run fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting the error between "let completePath" and "let nameOfPathHistory".even if I print something in between, I got the "Fatal error"  The function that I'm calling with completePath returns the value that it should return.

What is very strange for me is that when I build the App everything looks OK but when I run it then it appears the FATAL ERROR and the break point.

Does someone have an Idea why I'm getting this error?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var datePickerCpntainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet var selectedValueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var selectValuesButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var selectDate: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var historyImageView: UIImageView!
var selectedValuefromPicker:String! = ""
var selectedChildInPicker: String! = ""
var childValueString: String! = ""

var selectedDateInPickerBeginn: String! = ""
var timeStampBeginn:String! = ""

var selectedDateInPickerEnde:String! = ""
var timeStampEnde:String! = ""

@IBOutlet var greatView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

//var containerViewState : Bool

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    selectValuesButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    selectValuesButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    selectValuesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    selectDate.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    let catchPath = CatchPath()

        selectedValueLabel.text = selectedValuefromPicker
        childValueString = selectedChildInPicker

    print("------------->\(childValueString)")
            timeStampBeginn = selectedDateInPickerBeginn
            timeStampEnde = selectedDateInPickerEnde

    print("------------------\(timeStampEnde)")

            let completePath = catchPath.CatchThePathWithChid(childValueString,dateBeginn: timeStampBeginn, dateEnde: timeStampEnde)

            print(completePath)



            let nameOfPathHistory = catchPath.downloadPath(completePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


            ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(nameOfPathHistory, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { (image, url)  in

                self.historyImageView.image = image!
            }

}




@IBAction func selectItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    containerView.hidden = false

    func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(0.5)
        )
    }



    greatView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5e9400)
    historyImageView.alpha = 0.5
    selectValuesButton.alpha = 0.5
    selectDate.alpha = 0.5


}


@IBAction func selectDate(sender: AnyObject) {

    datePickerCpntainer.hidden = false
}


}
```

**update catchPath structure**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public struct CatchPath {



func downloadPath ( contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> String{
   var namePath:String = "http://wetter.htw-berlin.de/"

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding)


        namePath += content
        print(namePath)
    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return namePath

}
func CatchThePathWithChid (chidValue:String?,dateBeginn:String?, dateEnde:String?)-> NSURL {

    var completePathImage = NSURL(string: "")


    let completePathWitValuePicker = NSURL(string: "http://wetter.htw-berlin.de/phpFunctions/holePlot.php?begin=\(dateBeginn) &end=\(dateEnde)&\(chidValue)")

    if chidValue != nil && dateBeginn != ""  {

      var  completePath = NSURL(string: "http://wetter.htw-berlin.de/phpFunctions/holePlot.php?begin=\(dateBeginn) &end=\(dateEnde)&\(chidValue)")

       completePathImage = completePath

    } else  {

        let wetterURLString = NSURL(string: "http://wetter.htw-berlin.de/phpFunctions/holePlot.php?begin=1365976800&end=1366063200&chid[]=6")

        completePathImage = wetterURLString


    }



    print ("-------------------------->\(completePathImage)")




    return completePathWitValuePicker!
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the CatchPath class?

Comment: Do not use implicitly unwrapped optionals when you don't need them, otherwise they will come back to bite you like they just did. Code safe! Use optional binding with error handling, use optionality only when needed, etc, and these issues will disappear like magic.

Answer (score 0):

I would start to break up the code and wrap your assignments with "if let" optionals. The issue here is a dereference to an optional that you are forcing to use with the implicit unwrapped optional using "!".

Comment: but as far as I can see there is no optional that I'm forcing to use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! the problem was in the catchPath structure. the method "CatchThePathWithChid" was indeed returning a optional with value nil. I forgot to return the real variable, in this case "completePathImage". 
thank you all for your comments.

Comment: This type of crash most invariably comes from an optional that you dereference with the exclamation point. See my comment below.